# Azure Storage CloudBlob.Properties are not initialized when using GetBlobReference()

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to get some information about Azure blob (last modified UTC date time). This information is stored CloudBlob.Properties.LastModifiedUtc property.

If I use method GetBlobReference() or GetBlockBlobReference(), the Properties of the blob are not initialized (LastModifiedUtc is DateTime.MinDate). If I use ListBlobs() the Properties are initialized correctly (LastModifiedUtc has correct value).

Am I doing something wrong when using GetBlobReference function? Is there some way how to get CloudBlob instance just for one specific blob? I know I can missue ListBlobs() and filter just the blob I'm interested in, or use ListBlobsWithPrefix() from class CloudBlobClient, but I would expect to get all the metadata when I ask for specific Blob Reference.

Code showing how I'm working with Azure blobs:

```
    string storageAccountName = "test";
    string storageAccountKey = @"testkey";
    string blobUrl = "https://test.blob.core.windows.net";
    string containerName = "testcontainer";
    string blobName = "testbontainer";

    var credentials = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);
    var cloudBlobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobUrl, credentials);
    var containerReference = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(string.Format("{0}/{1}", blobUrl, containerName));

    // OK - Result is of type CloudBlockBlob, cloudBlob_ListBlobs.Properties.LastModifiedUtc > DateTime.MinValue
    var cloudBlob_ListBlobs = containerReference.ListBlobs().Where(i => i is CloudBlob && ((CloudBlob)i).Name == blobName).FirstOrDefault() as CloudBlob;

    // WRONG - Result is of type CloudBlob, cloudBlob_GetBlobReference.Properties.LastModifiedUtc == DateTime.MinValue
    var cloudBlob_GetBlobReference = containerReference.GetBlobReference(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", blobUrl, containerName, blobName));

    // WRONG - Result is of type CloudBlockBlob, cloudBlob_GetBlockBlobReference.Properties.LastModifiedUtc == DateTime.MinValue
    var cloudBlob_GetBlockBlobReference = containerReference.GetBlockBlobReference(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", blobUrl, containerName, blobName));
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe you have to make a seperate call to fetch the attributes/metadata. After you have the blob referrence, issue the following line to retrieve the attributes.

cloudBlob_GetBlobReference.FetchAttributes();

Comment: To elaborate, GetBlobReference() doesn't make any network calls. It pretty much just returns you an object that's initialized with the right URL. To get the attributes, you need to make a network call, and .FetchAttributes() is the way to minimally do that (does a HEAD request).

Comment: Oh, thanks, I was not aware that GetBlobReference() is just client side factory method, I expected it to make call against Azure and I was surprised it doesn't bring all the data. Now it makes sense to me.

Comment: priceless answer saved me a lot

Answer (score 2):

This relates to the Java SDK.  But having a [CloudBlob](http://dl.windowsazure.com/storage/javadoc/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html) derived `CloudBlockBlob` object, you may need the [CloudBlob.downloadAttributes()](http://dl.windowsazure.com/storage/javadoc/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html#downloadAttributes()) call.