# Microsoft Azure: how get md5-hash of a blob in Java

Tags: java, hash, azure, md5, blob

im storing some pictures in microsoft azure. the upload and download are working well. but i would like to verify the uploaded data with a md5-hash, independently from up- and downloading. so here is my code (the whole connection and account things works. container is also not null):

```
public String getHash(String remoteFolderName, String filePath) {

    CloudBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(remoteFolderName + "/" + filePath);

    return blob.properties.contentMD5
}
```

The problem is, that i always get null for each blob.
am i doing it in the right the right way or are there other possibilities to get a md5-hash of a blob?

Comment: What happens if you call `blob.FetchAttributes()` before accessing properties?

Comment: i think you mean blob.downloadAttributes(), because i cannot find a method called FetchAttributes(). indeed, i tried this too, but the result was the same. p.s.: i'm using microsoft-windowsazure-api-0.2.2.jar, and i have a student-account by azure

Comment: I've never seen the Java API of Azure SDK, I guess it indeed may have different name, yet it would be weird.

Comment: ive got it from here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but .NET SDK also has this problem. Referencing CloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentMD5 property returns null unless  FetchAttributes() was called on the blob reference object. 

Explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994777/azure-storage-cloudblob-properties-are-not-initialized-when-using-getblobreferen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MD5 hash will only be available if it was set when you uploaded the blob. See this post for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/18/windows-azure-blob-md5-overview.aspx

Is it possible the MD5 hash was never set for these blobs?

Comment: i suppose it must be the problem. i'm just uploading the files without setting the ContentMD5 property. i'll try to set this value before uploading, and post here the result asap

Comment: Since some time in 2012, it is set "automatically" for small blobs FWIW https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319211/32453

Answer (score 4):

I've solved this problem, in the way smarx have metnioned it. Before uploading I compute the md5-Hash for the file and update it in blob's properties:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.Base64;
import com.google.common.io.Files

String putFile(String remoteFolder, String filePath){
    File fileReference = new File (filePath)
    // the user is already authentificated and the container is not null
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(remoteFolderName+"/"+filePath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileReference)
    if(blob){
        BlobProperties props = blob.getProperties()

        MessageDigest md5digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
        String md5 = Base64.encode(Files.getDigest(fileReference, md5digest))

        props.setContentMD5(md5)
        blob.setProperties(props)
        blob.upload(fis, fileReference.length())
        return fileReference.getName()
   }else{
        //ErrorHandling
        return ""
   }
}
```

after the file is uploaded i can get the ContentMD5 with this method:

```
String getHash(String remoteFolderName, String filePath) {
    String fileName = new File(filePath).getName()
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(remoteFolderName+"/"+filePath)
    if(!blob) return ""
    blob.downloadAttributes()
    byte[] hash = Base64.decode(blob.getProperties().getContentMD5())
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, hash)
    return bigInt.toString(16).padLeft(32, '0')
}
```

Comment: These days it is "auto set" for small files, but not large ones, so manually setting it that way is probably safest https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319211/32453