# CONTENT-MD5 is missing AZURE portal

Tags: c#, azure, blob, md5

I'm uploading files in **AZURE** blob storage using **c#** library. If I upload a file with byte[], it calculates MD5 (verified in AZURE portal - displays **CONTENT-MD5** value).

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = GetUserProjectsBlob(blobName);
blockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(file, 0, file.Length);
```

I need to upload a large file into AZURE. So I'm using PutBlock & PutBlockList methods..

```
string blockHash = GetMd5FromStream(new MemoryStream(file));
blockBlob.PutBlock(blockId, new MemoryStream(file, true), blockHash);
// To commit transaction
blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockIDsBase64);
```

But in the above scenario, **CONTENT-MD5** is missing in the AZURE portal. I have also tried this..

```
BlobRequestOptions opt = new BlobRequestOptions();
opt.StoreBlobContentMD5 = true;
UseTransactionalMD5 = true;
blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockIDsBase64, null, opt);
```

But still no luck. Any ideas about how to resolve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this via code?  I only ask because AZCopy may work better if you are just copying files up

Comment: @JasonH I'm using it for WebApi.

Comment: I'm interested in another technical detail - is there a reason that you upload it block-by-block? Why aren't the full-blob uploading APIs (`UploadFromFIle`, `UploadFromStream`, ...) working for you?

Answer (score 3):

In the following lines of code:

```
string blockHash = GetMd5FromStream(new MemoryStream(file));
blockBlob.PutBlock(blockId, new MemoryStream(file, true), blockHash);
// To commit transaction
blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockIDsBase64);
```

You're actually calculating the MD5 hash of the block data. When Storage Service receives this data, it does the hash verification to ensure that block data is not corrupted.

```
BlobRequestOptions opt = new BlobRequestOptions();
opt.StoreBlobContentMD5 = true;
UseTransactionalMD5 = true;
blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockIDsBase64, null, opt);
```

Above code does not instruct Storage Service to calculate the hash of the blob you're uploading. You would need to calculate the MD5 hash of the blob yourself and send it as a part of properties doing something like:

```
blockBlob.Properties.ContentMD5 = "computed hash";
blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockIDsBase64, null, opt);
```

Comment: When you upload a file without breaking it in blocks, the SDK calculates the MD5 hash and that's why it is there. SDK doesn't calculate the hash if you upload a file by breaking it in blocks.

Comment: Yep, if you're uploading with your own block list, you have to manually add the theoretical MD5 for "all blocks when combined".  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319211/32453