# do azure calculate md5 checksum for all the blob uploaded in container?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I checked the blob properties, there I can find this field
contentMD5: <Buffer 01 ba 4f 35 88 e1 52 1f 3d c7 7......

just wanted to know, do azure populate this field for all the blob that is upload in storage account by any method(using blob API or portal) by-default. or we have to enable/set any property?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only on small file sizes. A member of the Azure org on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/495#issuecomment-532804913) noted:

> Content md5 is only stored by the service, and you cannot get it to calculate the md5 for you*. Your option one was the correct approach: to calculate the md5 locally and set the property.
>
> ...
>
> *If your blob is beneath a certain threshold in size, then the service will allow this on single-shot uploads. I believe this number is in the tens of megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any file you upload to Azure Blob Storage (using any method of uploading) has it's MD5 calculated automatically. It is part of it's "Properties" object, called `ContentMD5`. It's shown as a Base64 string in most of Azure's UIs, not as a hex string like what most of us are used to.

Comment: some files are having `CONTENT-MD5 -` it's not adding md5 for all the files

Comment: @gavisic -- then I would produce a test case showing it failed and file a bug report. I have been working in BlobStorage for years and use the hashes for everything. I have never not had one generate.

Comment: Just curious if you found a solution to this. A significant number of files in my blob storage have the checksum as empty and we are trying to come up with an efficient way to compute check sum for them

Comment: Small ones don't, see the other answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319211/32453

Comment: Azure Storage can't compute MD5 if it wasn't set during the upload. You can however update the blob property and set it's MD5 from client.