# Recalculate MD5 on Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, md5

We have a lot of files which were uploaded to Azure Blob storage where the MD5 was not calculated and thus it is empty at the moment.
Is there a way to recalculate them?
I have a list with all files where it is empty, but downloading and re-uploading isn't a good option since it concerns more then 1TB of files.

Comment: I think both will answer you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364773/do-azure-calculate-md5-checksum-for-all-the-blob-uploaded-in-container and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229153/how-to-check-azure-storage-blob-file-uploaded-correctly/69319211#69319211

Comment: Hi, I've found those as well, but neither of them really answers the question. I know why it is empty in the first place, but is there a way to re-calculate it?